# How does the process of finding descriptive rules of language differ from prescriptive ones?

Tags: grammar

How exactly does the research of writing a prescriptive  grammar book differ from that of a descriptive one? I imagine that both would involve reading modern day literature, so how could they be different?

Comment: To write a prescriptive grammar you either read and regurgitate what other prescriptive grammarians have written, or you make something up, or a combination of the two. Those are the only options.

Comment: So prescriptive grammarians originally just made things up? Bruv

Comment: Prescriptive grammar means a grammar that prescribes. It can be based on anything or nothing.

Comment: @Buraian Basically, yes. Or they plagiarised from the other prescriptivists who made them up originally. Descriptive grammars describe what a particular speech community do. They need to look at what people do, not what people say people ought to do. In theory, they do not need to read the literature (but in practice the rules underlying what people do are vast and complex, so people have to look at other people's research).

Comment: TO be fair, prescriptive grammarians don't necessarily realise they are making things up. They may think they are bringing order to a confused situation, deducing rules that make things "simpler" (or closer to how they speak) and that therefore  must be "right".

Comment: @ColinFine They may not realise it, but they are!

Answer (score 4):

Based on the argument in the comments of the other answer, I think in large part, the real difference between descriptive and prescriptive grammar is based on an is/ought distinction,

i.e.

How the language **is**

vs

How the language **ought to be**

So when you describe how a language **is** spoken, using research, that's descriptivism.

But looking back in history at the prescriptivists, when we look at them in good faith, the best of them were trying to shape English aesthetically, often referencing the real descriptive grammars of Latin, and advocating for the latinization of English. So in that case, prescriptivism wasn't descriptive either because of misapplication of rules or because of their advocacy to change the language that people used.

In that sense, any guidelines to language usage for the sake of aesthetics or clarity or what have you are literally prescriptive, and it really doesn't matter where they get their information from. A description is the goal of good linguists, since we want real data and real insight into language use and change. Yet, any application of that data to influence use of language must become prescriptive. So really the difference would lie in the use of your data, no matter how good or bad it is. Even with pure data, it could either be applied to change language or to better interpret it. Where classic prescriptions aimed at beauty, the normal sense is that clarity is a better goal. But that's still a goal.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental difference is that prescriptive language description *asserts* some standard of acceptability, and states "You should do this". A descriptive account of language *observes* what is accepted, and makes no recommendations. There may be some methodological overlap when a prescriptive standard is devised by inspecting a particular subset of literature ("the best literature") and inferring the rules which hold of that subset. However, actual research into language in constructing a prescriptive grammar is rare, instead, an author will simply re-state the conclusions of other authorities in the realm of prescriptive grammar. A descriptive grammar at least ostensibly involves significant inspection of actual language usage (though that might take the form of integrating previous descriptive conclusions, for example one does not re-invent the descriptive wheel of Classical Arabic verb paradigms in describing that language, one calls on prior knowledge about what the facts of the language are).

Comment: I think the following part of the answer is very misleading '*There may be some methodological overlap when a prescriptive standard is devised by inspecting a particular subset of literature (the "best literature")*.' This implies that some prescriptivist grammatical rules have been formulated at some point in this way. In actual fact, the (gold) standard way of debunking prescriptivist rules is to go straight to the great works of expert users of the language and show they do not use those rules. I don't think *any* prescriptivist rules have *ever* been derived that way.

Comment: @Araucaria-him Why do you think so, your opinion seams to be extremely simplified. A prescribing grammar handbook can be decivesed in the very same way as the merely describing one. The difference is whether rules are taken as prescriptions or not.

Comment: And in the end, when teaching the language, you have to say which answer is gonna get accepted in the FCE or TOEFL or whatever equivalent in whatever language. Or what kind speech csn be used by news anchors in BBC or CNN so that the viewers can actually understand what they are saying.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Which answer will get the best marks in FCE or TOEFL has nothing to do with prescriptivist grammar, though. (Actually, that's wrong. Following prescriptivist rules will help you fail your FCE or TOEFL exam.) Language learning 'grammars' are usually plagiarised and not based on research. The exceptional ones which aren't (for example Carter & McCarthy in relation to English) are descriptive. What they usually teach you is how people of a target language community speak.

Comment: @Araucaria-him You are saying that prescriptivist only means the latinizing 18th or 19th century grammarians? That is a very narrow view. There is much more to [linguistic prescription](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription), which is "is the establishment of rules defining preferred usage of language." in general.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Not at all. Where did I say that? Twentieth century examples abound (have a nose around Strunk & White, or Fowler). You cite "There is much more to linguistic prescription, which is "is the establishment of rules defining preferred usage of language." in general" <--- That's why it is not grammar. There are no preferred rules of grammar. Just like there are no preferred rules of biology.

Comment: And indeed many language prescriptions come from careful descriptive study of corpora, often from literature using some authors that are considered good enough. Saying that making prescriptions is just making things up is **extremely** oversimplifying. Maybe that was true once for English. But there are many other language prescriptions in the world and often continuously updated to follow the usage in contemporary literature (with some delay).

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава "indeed many language prescriptions come from careful descriptive study of corpora" <-- Can you name some? Or substantiate that claim with an example rule and the corpora that were used and the people that came up with the rule?

Comment: Standard Czech (as opposed to Common Czech), for example. But many other language standards, just look in the link I gave https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription#Formal_regulation

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Describing the grammar of a target speech community (for example a prestige variety) is not language prescriptivism.